# Bathroom light switch changed, now the light only turns on when the fan switch is turned on.

Tags: bathroom, switch, light, fans

I switched the light switch in the bathroom today because the toggle broke off.  I took out the old one, which is the Leviton 15 Amp Duplex Style Single-Pole / 3-Way AC Combination Toggle Light Switch and put in the Leviton 15  Amp Combination Double Switch.  The are almost identical and I put the wires back the same, but now the light only turns on when the switch for the fan is also on.  The fan comes on regardless of the light being off or on. Any advice?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring?

Answer (score 1):

No, you didn't put the wires back the same.  You switched sides.   Or the new model of switch switched sides*.

Put the old switch back on Just as it was.  Only this time, instead of looking at the physical position of the screws, look at the *function* of the screws.  One screw will be "common", the others switched.  Find those on the new switch.

* The physical position of switch screws varies wildly from switch to switch.  I have never done a 3-way swap where the common and travelers were in the same place on the old vs new switch. There are only 12 possibilities, how can every single switch be different??

Comment: The functions for the screws are the same on both switches.  The only difference is the old one has 3 screws “A1” “B1” and “A2” and the new one only has 2 screws A1 and B1.  I put the wires back at the same function as before. I’ll try to add pics later.